# Exe Is not Running at Windwows 32 bit OS

Tags: windows, winforms

I am making An Application on windows 7 using Visual Studio 2012,
before compile It I set A platform target to Any CPU.

It working fine with Windows and upper Versions.

but when i want to use this exe with Windows xp This is not working .

win 32 is not a valid application show error like this.

if i change it with Platform target to X86

then i am facing same problem?

Comment: what dotnet framework are u using ? Windows XP only supports up to 3.5 if I remember correctly

Comment: Is this a native or managed application? Visual Studio 2012 should be able to target Windows XP out the box. Just open the projects properties, go to General under configuration properties and check the Platform Toolset setting is set to a toolset such as "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)" or "Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)" and NOT "Visual Studio 2013 (v120)". The most recent platform toolsets place a minimum OS version in the EXE header that does not allow execution on XP.